# Можно ли предпринять какие-то меры, чтобы поработать через незащищенный вай-фай?

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, wifi

Допустим, за рубежом или где-то понадобится поработать, и хочется обезопасить себя от кражи какой-то информации.

Comment: VPN, очевидно..

Comment: Работать только через HTTPS. Зависит от того, с чем вы будете работать.